# Quiz disappears when I add more questions (JS), how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found a pen online, a quiz, which I could use. So I edited it and so.

This is the JS that still works, the quiz answers will still appear on the website

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ptkrngza/2/
```

(in this Fiddle it is still not working :( So that's weird, but it is actually working in Coda/My browser, and I suppose it's really all about the Javascript right?) But if it helps, this is the original codepen

```
https://codepen.io/nicklemmon/full/LpZKBO
```

en this is a Fiddle with the JS, that is not working.

```
jsfiddle.net/k0ns63a9/
```

So it's all about the js i think? Whenever I put in 4 questions, it just works. But when I add more questions, in the browser the questions/answers just disappear. But what do I have to change on the js so that the quiz still works properly (but with more questions)?

I can't really figure it out on my own unfortunately

Thanks!! If more info is needed I am more than willing to give them to you. Although I think someone good in javascript will figure it out pretty quick :p

Thank you!

Edit: so the question is basically: what do I have to edit on the JS of that Codepen so that I can add more questions to the quiz en the JS/Website will still work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems: your array elements are missing the separating commas, and jQuery isn't being loaded.

I found this by using the browser's developer tools window. (F12 in Chrome or Hamburger menu > More tools > Developer tools).

1) [I changed the focus to be the results pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlrNa.png)

2) [Running the code we can see three errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raJii.png). The first is because the Javascript interpreter expects a comma between array elements. Fix that first.

3) [After fixing the commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg2y0.png) we can see that it can't find the scripts you've specified at the end of your HTML, and that jQuery isn't being loaded. If we look at the CodePen, we can see that they're [loading jQuery as an external script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri12s.png) We need to do the same in JSFiddle. Add a jQuery CDN URL, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDjWx.png), paste it in [and done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzio.png).

[Runs perfectly now!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FObWl.png)